# Custom controller route to update column active to false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

I am trying to link to a custom controller route action and I'm doing something wrong. I have a Document model that handles uploading documents to my CRUD app. I want users to be able to 'delete' something, but not actually delete it from the system, but rather update the column 'active' to false. Then if someone with admin privileges can go ahead an complete the deletion. This process is needed because the app gets audited and we do not want to accidentally delete uploaded files.

I can't get the custom update action (remove) to work. When I rake routes I see:

```
remove_documents PUT      /documents/remove(.:format)                                                             document#remove
```

In my routes file (I'll a couple similar routes I'll want to add later so I used collection it up this way):

```
resources :documents do
  collection do
    put "remove", to: "document#remove", as: :remove
  end
end
```

In the Documents index view:

```
<%= link_to remove_documents_url(document), :method => :put do %>
  <span class="fa fa-trash text-danger"></span>
<% end %>
```

My Controller:

```
def remove
  @document = Document.find(params[:id])
  @document.active = false
  @document.save
  html { redirect_to(:back, :notice => 'Document was successfully removed.')}
end
```

The link works, but then I get the following error:

```
NameError at /documents/remove.75 uninitialized constant DocumentController

      raise unless e.missing_name? qualified_name_for(parent, const_name)
    end
  end
  name_error = NameError.new("uninitialized constant #{qualified_name}", const_name)
  name_error.set_backtrace(caller.reject {|l| l.starts_with? __FILE__ })
  raise name_error
end
# Remove the constants that have been autoloaded, and those that have been
# marked for unloading. Before each constant is removed a callback is sent
```

Comment: Can you add the whole error?

Comment: I added more of what I saw from better errors

Comment: @BenPohl The controller name must be plural : `put "remove", to: "documents#remove", as: :remove`

Comment: Thank you @sovalina. Now I have a new error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /documents/remove.66
Couldn't find Document with 'id'=

Comment: I'm not sure how to pass the params id. I'm assuming that this is taken care of for you in some of the Rails restful routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `remove` action on a specific `Document`, change the routes to :

```
resources :documents do
  member do
    put "remove", to: "documents#remove", as: :remove
  end
end
```

which gives you : `remove_document PUT  /documents/:id/remove(.:format)`
and use it like :

```
<%= link_to remove_document_path(document), :method => :put do %>
  <span class="fa fa-trash text-danger"></span>
<% end %>
```